# social features- chat, forums, online directories

Tags: chat, collaboration, forums

We are building a content based portal. Along with the content, we want to provide some collaborative tools- i.e. chat, forums, online directories etc

We are hoping to leverage open-source software for this, as this isn't really a differentiator and will hopefully be faster/cheaper. I am looking at light integration between the content and these (common login, ability to easily reference content in chat/ forums etc) and am flexible on features being offered- as long as the broad functionality is achieved.

We have hosted on MS Azure- what should our considerations be towards identifying the right product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla! is one option. You want to ensure that the majority or all of the tools you are looking for are openly available no your chosen platform. It is hard to make a solid recommendation without much detail on the content, but you can check it out here:

http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html

It is free and open source, site says

Joomla is used all over the world to power Web sites of all shapes and sizes. For example:

Corporate Web sites or portals
Corporate intranets and extranets

Disclaimer: Have never used Joomla

Comment: Just checked Jhoomla- does it provide the collaboration aspects required? also it is mentioned as a CMS for websites- is it the right choice for my need? I have the content built via a parallel process and loading via visual studio to host on Azure

Comment: I guess it depends on whether on not you have a developer to make it suit your needs. Is the portal for internal use, or will it be on the nets?